# Jetpack Compose - Convert classic TextApperance into compose TextStyle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My app read some `TextAppearance` object through attributes such as `R.attr.textAppearanceHeadline1`) from an app with Material design and I wanted to use them to as the `Typography` create a Compose `MateiralTheme`.

`Typography` works with Compose specific `TextStyle`s, are there any conversion utils to convert `TextAppearance` into `TextStyle` ?